# MySQL PDO query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to reduce this script execution time. It queries a database with about 2 million records about 1000 times on a loop:

```
foreach ($ids as $id){
    $stmt=$dbh->query("SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM `ids` 
                WHERE $id BETWEEN `id_start` AND `id_end`");
    $rows[] = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

It takes forever on a 4 core 8 GB machine (about 800 seconds!). Id groups do not overlap, ids tend to be from just a few different groups in each execution and I have indexed both (id_start,id_end) and (id_end).

Caching improves very much the situation (running the same 1000 values more than once is just a few seconds), but I would like to know what can I do to speed up non cached queries.

Example output of EXPLAIN:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table"     "type"  "possible_keys"     "key"               "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "ids"       "range" "id_start,id_end"   "id_start,id_end"   "5"          ""     "52508" "Using index condition"
```

**EDIT**: Instead of "Using index condition" I get "Using where" sometimes (Not sure but I think from id values higher than 840771583) Why?

**EDIT 2**: Full create code:

```
CREATE TABLE `ids` (
    `id_start` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_end` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `iso-639-1` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `country_name` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `region_name` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `city_name` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `area_code` VARCHAR(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `timezone` VARCHAR(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_startid_end` (`id_start`, `id_end`),
    INDEX `id_end` (`id_end`),
    INDEX `country_name` (`country_name`),
    INDEX `region_name` (`region_name`),
    INDEX `city_name` (`city_name`),
    INDEX `area_code` (`area_code`),
    INDEX `iso-639-1` (`iso-639-1`),
    INDEX `timezone` (`timezone`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say about the queries? Does it use the indexes?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it does seem so. I edited to add the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Does this table is a read only table? Assuming "Read/Write Splitting". And which storage engine does it use?

Comment: You should really be preparing your query outside the loop and binding the `$id` as a parameter. One statement executed multiple times is always better

Comment: Do the intervals `(id_start,id_end)` overlap, i.e. is there a chance that a query will return more than one row? If they do not overlap, see my answer here, in an almost identical question: [Slow Query Gets Even Slower After Indexing](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33133/slow-query-gets-even-slower-after-indexing/33139#33139)

Comment: @Phil That's what I first tried (with PDO::EMULATE_PREPARES attribute set to false), but surprisingly it's exactly the same so I posted here a simpler form of the query.

Comment: @ypercube No,as I state on the question the intervals do not overlap.

Comment: No surprise actually. A prepared statment can add its tiny bit of optimization only if your query optimized itself. While if it's **query execution** that takes **all** the time - to save a millisecond on execution plan creation won't make any difference.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you run `set profiling=1; your query; show profile;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the intervals do not overlap, try this rewriting of the query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ids
WHERE id_start =
      ( SELECT MAX(id_start) 
        FROM ids
        WHERE id_start <= $id
      )
  AND $id <= id_end ;
```

Comment: WHOA!!! Magic!!! Only 1 second for 1000 queries! How did you do it? What's happening here?

Comment: Sorry, not much time today. I can expand the answer with explanation later tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: After browsing a little from the link you posted on your first comment, I see that in the original query there are only 52508 examined rows (rows in the range, I guess) out from a total of 1822141 rows the table has. The query you proposed uses index fseek, which is way faster than sequential index fscan when there is only a small number of rows to be examined, because despite being slower at reading contiguous rows it can skip rows. Am I right? I haven't got yet to why overlapping is important but I'm working my way out towards it :-)

Comment: Yes, correct, the subquery does an index seek. The EXPLAIN should show "Select tables optimized away" which means the MAX() was found using only an index seek. See [EXPLAIN Output Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html) for more details. The Uniqueness is needed so we are sure that it will indeed return the value we need (if a matching interval exists.) It also guarantees that the external query - although it does a range check - will return only one row, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
It queries a database with about 2 million records about 1000 times on a loop:
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

## HERE

is your problem.

It should be a single query for sure.

Also consider tweaking mysql daemon, to make sure if key buffer size is enough.

this question has absolutely nothing to do with PDO, btw. When dealing with a problem you have to narrow it down as much as possible, taking out ALL the unnecessary parts. Speaking of the query, you have to take it into console and play there.

Comment: I specified I was using PDO just in case the driver could provide some form of optimization (like prepared statements which I tried but didn't improve anything). I work my queries from the console, of course. I will try forming big queries grouping multiple ids but the output must be ordered by id so I don't know if that is going to work much better...

Comment: Using only one query it takes little less time, even without ordering it's still more than 5 minutes for a query with 1000 requests, and somehow I get less than 1000 rows, so the query is not even working properly (I'm using the same query, but with `WHERE $id BETWEEN id_start AND id_end OR $id2 BETWEEEN id_start AND id_end`, etc. instead). I also increased the innodb buffer pool size without luck, probably because of what this post says about small databases being already fully cached: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/214401